# Thread-safe progressive downloading in Android

Tags: android, http, download, progress

I am writing an Android application that has to download quite a lot of image files; the previous dev wrote it using various HttpClient type classes.  These give no progress information whatever, and if the download fails part-way through there is no way to recover the missing bits (as far as I can find out).

We want to be able to report progress to the user, particularly if it is slow, and we want to be able to resume downloads, so I reimplemented this using HttpUrlConnection.  It works fine single-threaded, but not multithreaded: I don't know what happens exactly but the images are getting corrupted.  Android says that instances of this are indeed not thread safe.

As far as I can tell this means we have to choose between multithreaded downloads (which my colleague reports are slightly faster) and the ability to resume.  Is there any way to get both on Android, short of implementing my own, thread-safe HTTP connection class?

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind.  The AsyncTask class (see: [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)) is built for this sort of thing, and the [new DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class was developed as a rather robust method that restarts if necessary, persists through device restarts, etc.  Obviously it really depends on your situation, but give those a look and see if they're something you need.

Comment: These are already running inside 'AsyncTasks'; the problem is the downloads seem to be interacting with each other. DownloadManager does look like a good bet though, thanks.